# check box checked by default on page load

Tags: jquery

Below is my working code but the only problem is, I want the check box to checked by default and show the jquery output on page load but it only show output when i re-check the check box.

```js
$(function() {
  $defaultValue = $('#total').val();
  $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(event) {
    var total = 0;
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
      total += parseInt($(this).parent().find('.inv-total').text().substring(1));
    });

    if (total == 0) {
      $('#total').val($defaultValue);
    } else {
      $('#total').val('$' + total);
    }
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="invoice">
  <input type="checkbox" checked='checked' value="1" />
  <span class="inv-total">$100</span>
</div>

<input type="text" id="total" value="$90" />
```

Comment: where did you place your code? For me this is working fine without changing anything: http://jsfiddle.net/wx216kzr/24/

Comment: I am getting "$100" on re-check of checkbox.

Comment: you assign your code to show the value only on click of the checkbox. that's why it is only showing up when you click on the checkbox and not on pageLoad.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $defaultValue = $('#total').val();
    checkCheckboxes();

    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(event) {
      checkCheckboxes();
    })

    function checkCheckboxes() {
      total = 0;
      $("input:checked").each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).parent().find('.inv-total').text().substring(1));
      });

      if (total == 0) {
        $('#total').val($defaultValue);
      } else {
        $('#total').val('$' + total);
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.trigger('click')` twice to uncheck and check the checkbox:

```js
$(function() {
  $defaultValue = $('#total').val();
  $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(event) {
    var total = 0;
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
      total += parseInt($(this).parent().find('.inv-total').text().substring(1));
    });

    if (total == 0) {
      $('#total').val($defaultValue);
    } else {
      $('#total').val('$' + total);
    }
  }).trigger('click').trigger('click');

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="invoice">
  <input type="checkbox" checked='checked' value="1" />
  <span class="inv-total">$100</span>
</div>

<input type="text" id="total" value="$90" />
```

Comment: output changed but check box is not checked on page load

Comment: The checkbox in the sample above isn't checked for you?

Comment: Ok....its working on using 'id' but when use 'class' its not working.   MY CODE: `$(function() {
  $defaultValue = $('.total').val();
  $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(event) {
    var total = 0;
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
      total += parseInt($(this).parent().find('.inv-total').text().substring(1));
    });

    if (total == 0) {
      $('.total').val($defaultValue);
    } else {
      $('.total').val('$' + total);
    }
  }).trigger('click').trigger('click');

})`